Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" but Uniprot IDs are there
I'm trying to stringify my gene network in Cytoscape and have designated a column with uniprot IDs for the basis of the search. Not every gene has a uniprot ID but I have selected to retain genes without them. For some reason I am unable to execute this function and receive  the feedback:
"Stringify network
 Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "java.util.List.get(int)" is null"
I have verified the uniprot IDs are correct and exist with singular matches to the database, could anyone give insight into how I might overcome this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you provide a backtrace when you get this error?  You can get it by running Cytoscape from a command shell, but you can also get provide the backtrace that shows up in your CytoscapeConfiguration/3/framework-cytoscape.log  That will help us figure out exactly where the problem is.
